# Scope of a pointer in memory

Tags: c, pointers, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have been studying C for the past weeks, but I can't fully understand how memory manages pointers.

My question arises from this example obtained from here(page 17 of 19): [C-Pointer-Basics](https://www.slideshare.net/richieellis42/c-pointer-basics)

Example code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 void F(int, int *);

 int main()
 {
     int m = 3;
     int n = 5;

     F(m, &n);

     printf("main: %d, %d\n", m, n); // print 3 7 (Where does the 7 came from?)

     return 0;
 }

 void F(int a, int *b)
 {
     /*
      * `a` being a local variable, gets cleaned after `F()` ends
      *  BUT how does `b` retain the value of `&a`?
      */

     a = 7;
     *b = a; // `*b = 7`
     b = &a; // `b` points to `a`
     *b = 4; // `a = 4` and why `*b` doesn't return 4?

     printf("F: %d, %d\n", a, *b); // print 4 4
 }
```

The question here is:

Why when `main()` prints the values of `m` and `n`, It shows`m = 3` and `n = 7`?

My assumptions:

As I know, a pointer goes beyond the scope of the function where it is declared, so in `void F(int a, int *b)` when the function is no longer needed, it gets destroyed, same with his parameters, BUT the value of `int *b` remains in memory right(even though `int *b` no longer exists)? So if this is true, we can 'recover' it from memory and use it in `main()`.

Best,

Comment: This is where single-stepping through the code with a debugger would be very helpful. The 7 comes from `*b = a;` where you copy the contents of a into the location where b points at.

Comment: @Lundin, tanks for the advise, I'll be doing some tests like this one, but using a debugger, it would be a lot easier to understand what is happening now that I understand a bit better the use of pointers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the question why `m` and `n` print `3,7` is because the first parameter is passed by value hence it is only getting copied, therefore no modification of the original `m` is happening and in the case of `n`, you're passing its address so when you do `*b=a` the value of `a` gets copied to `n`. And then when you do `b=&a` the pointer `b` now starts pointing to the address of `a` instead of that of `n`. Which is why the second time you do `*b=4`, you are not modifying `n` but `a`.

Comment: really thanks for your help, it was so obvious now that I understand what was happening, again, thanks

Comment: no problem @PaulS-Pou, it took me a long time to master pointer. I'm aware of how confusing it can become.